# Why isn't the port specified in "pxssh.pxssh()" in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pxssh

https://github.com/tatmush/violentPython3/blob/master/Chapter-2/3-sshBrute.py

```
s = pxssh.pxssh()

s.login(host, user, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's specified as an ssh option like in the following example:

```
from pexpect import pxssh
s = pxssh.pxssh(options={
                    "StrictHostKeyChecking": "no",
                    "UserKnownHostsFile": "/dev/null"})
```

The above snippet is from the documentation on pxssh: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html

Comment: But, in the code above, it's not specified anywhere, which leads me to believe that it's not necessary in this case. And if it's not necessary, I would like to know why, if you could help me with such a thing.

Comment: Was the code above a snippet or the entire script?  Like, maybe they specified it before the shown code.  Alternatively, ssh and, by extension, pxssh both have default ports.  If one isn't specified, it will attempt to connect using the default port specified in your config files.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I just did an nmap scan, and the default port is 22.